# LyX: How to scale a figure to more than 100% text width and have it centered?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

Actually, the title says it all. I can scale a picture to >100% text width, but it will always have its left edge aligned with the text block, so will stick out at the right side. What I want is a centered picture that sticks out equally left and right. How can that be achieved in LyX?

Comment: If you use an ERT box on the left of the graphic with `\centerline{` and then a different ERT box on the right with `}`, does that do what you want?

Comment: @scottkosty would that be within the figure float or outside of it?

Comment: Not sure :). I guess try both ways.

Comment: Tried it. Outside produces an error, but inside works as advertised. Thank you! Please write an answer so I can upvote and accept!

Comment: Great! If you don't mind and have the time, can you write an answer with the steps in LyX (specifically putting the cursor inside the float)?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `\centerline` is a plainTeX macro that does not leave vmode, thus it can make unwanted  output if not dealt with care. I would suggest using the package `adjustbox` with the `export` options, which makes the command `\includegraphics` inherit all the `\adjustbox` options (including the option `center`).

To add the package in LyX, write `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in `Document->Settings->Latex Preamble`.

To use the center option, in LyXs graphics dialog write `center` in `Latex and LyX options->Latex options`

Another option is to wrap the graphics inside `makebox` with the width of `\textwidth`. To do that, select your graphics, then go to `Insert->Box->Frameless`, In the boc settings switch the Inner Box to Makebox and set the width of the box to 100% of Text Width

Answer (score 0):

All the credits for this answer go to @scottkosty.

All you need to do is to bracket the figure within its float box with some evil red text (LyX menu item TeX-Code). Into the ERT box to the left of the picture enter `\centerline{` and into the second ERT box to the right of the picture enter just `}`.

Please note that the two ERT boxes go directly left and right of the picture and not outside of the float box. Then the picture will be centered with as much overhang to the left as to the right.